# How to provide space between two contents by using flex in vue.js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I developed one card  which contains several sections ,my requirement is after Rs.1500 (class="price-section") i want to print same line of (2000)[label], i tried different ways but it's not happening please help me to acheive this thing[[like this i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFFAF.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFFAF.png).[image: like this i am getting]

`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-section">
            Don't Make Me Think
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by tarun
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. 1500 <label>(2000)</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</template>
<style  scoped>
.price-section{
text-align: left;
font: normal normal bold 12px/16px Roboto;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #0A0102;
opacity: 1;
margin-left:20px;
width: 48px;
height: 16px;
margin-top:26px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

}
label{
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
    font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #878787;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 36px;
    height: 13px;
    /* margin-left:73px; */
   
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:flex` is normally enough to place items horizontally adjacent to each other (as `row` is the default `flow-direction`). The problem is `.price-section` has a very narrow `width`, so there's no room for the `<label>` to be placed on the same line.

The solution is to remove the `width` from `.price-section`, which allows the items to be on the same line. Then apply a `margin-left` on `label` to add some spacing:

```css
.price-section {
  /*width: 48px;*/
}

label {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-flex-items?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks alot @tony19,now I am getting a perspective where did I mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `span` tag and `justify-content: flex-start` or `justify-content: space-between;`  properties

```
<div class="price-section">
    <span>Rs. 1500<span><label>(2000)</label>
</div>
```

Style

```
.price-section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: remove `width: 48px;` or add more `width`

Answer (score 0):

Try this once. Sample working code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-darkness-3cjhs)

```
<div class="price-section">
    <b>Rs. 1500</b> <span>(2000)</span>
</div>
```

---

```
.price-section{
   position: relative;
}

.price-section span {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   text-decoration-line: line-through;
   font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   color: #878787;
   padding-left: 5px;
}
```